# Windows 7 login page freezes

Tags: windows-7

When it powers on, it comes to the login page and freezes. The mouse moves,and I see my name but when I click it does not open or shows a login field. On a Dell Latitude E7440. Also, when I press the shut down icon it lights but does nothing.
Please advise help

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl-Alt-Delete; this worked for me when the login was unresponsive.
When my Windows box freezes, this shortcut returns focus to any fields that do not respond to the mouse.

Comment: I doubt CTRL + ALT + DELETE would do any good